# Is there any ways to create new locale in android studio?

Tags: android, locale

I want create new Locale which does not have Android Studio
**uz_Cyrl** cyrillic alphabet
AS has its latin alphabet

Comment: what is your language code and country code ?

Comment: language code is uz

Comment: country code is 998

Comment: it has latin alphabet and i also want to add cyrillic

Comment: https://lokalise.com/blog/android-app-localization/
This link may help.

Comment: @dennisrufigill its another,
I want to create new Locale